# Java equivalent ( or similar ) to powershell

Tags: java, powershell, jmx

I am aware of JMX, however I would not consider it anywhere near or equivalent to PowerShell or some other command-line/shell. For instance, JMX Beans and JConsole seem more like a GUI, where the user can perform operations only provided they are directly available by said bean. You cannot do more complex operations like filter, pipe, etc. This is where command-lines/shells like PowerShell go a little further.

Can anyone make any suggestions towards creating something more like PowerShell and less like JMX?

What FOSS libraries can help me get there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can use Groovy or Scala, both have a "shell" feature. In fact most dynamic languages for the JVM have a shell like interpreter.

Comment: true, but they are shells for the language itself with little or no file utilities etc to do the boring admin type stuff. I know i could add support to enable the user to telnet into a gr/sc shell shell but that is bare... After all once they are "in" what do they do, how can they do stuff w/ your system its not very obvious.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) ?

Comment: It provides command line access and is under LGPL. It should meet the requirements ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) has a console system built-in that's easy to extend. I don't know if it can call JMX without a bit of work, but I do know it's very easy to add commands to it.

Not as comprehensive as powershell, but it might be good enough to get the job done for you.